# Angularjs search from string start

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter

is there any way to compare strings starting from first char (not comparing chars inside a existing string.

example:
I have array with "Boobo", "Frodo", "Ookami" "Waki", "Konsta", "Perrys", "Ami". 
And when i have default search filter, after typing "O" in input i will get Boobo, Frodo, Ookami, Konsta because they have "o" letter inside. 
What i want is to get only Ookami, because this name starts with "o", after typing. 
Strict comparison isn`t a solution, because i would have to type whole name to get it showed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom filter:
[startswith angular filter](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/filters/startsWith)

This allows you to say:

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in things | startsWith: search">{{thing}}</li>
```

instead of

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: search">{{thing}}</li>
```